# remove repetitive string in the sequence of strings and keep only those appear at the last time

Tags: r, string

I have a dictionary of words. I also have a column in a dataframe including the sequence of combinations of the words in the dictionary.
I want to remove repetitive words and keep only those appear last time in the sequence. So, we will have each unique word that appear as its last time. For example, if dictionary<- c("A","B","C") and my sequence is mySeq<-"ABCCBCA" I want the result to be: "BCA"

lets try it in following data

```
dic<- c("AA","BB","c","p")

df<-read.table(text="
id  mySequece
1   AAcAABBcPAA
2   AABBAA
3   AABBAABB
4   AAcBBc
5   cBBAABBBBBBBB
6   cBBAABBBBcBB
7   ccp
8   ccppcc",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

desired result:

id  My_new_sequence
1   BBcPAA
2   BBAA
3   AABB
4   AABBc
5   cAABB
6   AAcBB
7   cp
8   pc
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: @akrun I really appreciate your help. you always answer my questions quickly and correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the elements based on the 'dic', then use `duplicated` to remove the duplicates from the end and `paste` it together

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(mySequece = str_extract_all(mySequece, str_c(dic, collapse="|")) %>% 
                 map_chr(~  str_c(.x[!duplicated(.x,
                     fromLast = TRUE)], collapse="")))
#  id mySequece
#1  1     BBcAA
#2  2      BBAA
#3  3      AABB
#4  4     AABBc
#5  5     cAABB
#6  6     AAcBB
#7  7        cp
#8  8        pc
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sapply(regmatches(df$mySequece, gregexpr(paste(dic, collapse="|"), 
  df$mySequece)), function(x)
    paste(x[!duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)], collapse=""))
#[1] "BBcAA" "BBAA"  "AABB"  "AABBc" "cAABB" "AAcBB" "cp"    "pc"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:8, mySequece = c("AAcAABBcPAA", "AABBAA", 
"AABBAABB", "AAcBBc", "cBBAABBBBBBBB", "cBBAABBBBcBB", "ccp", 
"ccppcc")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```